# C: Check if one element of an array equals another element

Tags: c, arrays, element, equals

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
float dlvelox;
float dlveloy;
float lvelox[1000] = {};
float lveloy[1000] = {};
float xcord[1000] = {};
float ycord[1000] = {};
float length;
float breadth;
int id;
int j;
int k;
int stepcount;
int step = 0;


/* Obtaining velocity */
{
    printf("Enter the initial h velocity of the ball:\n");
    scanf("%f", &dlvelox);
    printf("Enter the initial v velocity of the ball:\n");
    scanf("%f", &dlveloy);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    lvelox[i] = dlvelox;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    lveloy[i] = dlveloy;

/* Initializing box lock */
{
    printf("Enter the length of box:\n");
    scanf("%f", &length);
    printf("Enter the breadth of box:\n");
    scanf("%f", &breadth);
}

/* Obtain number of steps */
{
    printf("Enter the number of steps wanted:\n");
    scanf("%d", &stepcount);
}

/* Initial console display */
{
    printf("\n");
    printf("X-coordinate, Y-coordinate, Ball ID, Step\n");
    printf("\n");

}

/* Loop method */
while ( step < stepcount )
{    

    j = id;
    k = id;

    for(id = 0; id < 1000; id++)
    {
            lveloy[id] = lveloy[id] - 9.81;
            xcord[id] = xcord[id] + lvelox[id];
            ycord[id] = ycord[id] + lveloy[id];
            printf("%f, %f, %d, %d\n", xcord[id], ycord[id], id, step);

    if ( ycord[id] < 0 )
    {
            lveloy[id] = (lveloy[id] * -1);
            xcord[id] = xcord[id] + lvelox[id];
            ycord[id] = ycord[id] + lveloy[id];
            printf("%f, %f, %d, %d\n", xcord[id], ycord[id], id, step);
    }

    if ( ycord[id] > breadth )
    {
            lveloy[id] = (lveloy[id] * -1);
            xcord[id] = xcord[id] + lvelox[id];
            ycord[id] = ycord[id] + lveloy[id];
            printf("%f, %f, %d, %d\n", xcord[id], ycord[id], id, step);
    }

    if ( xcord[id] < 0 )
    {
            lvelox[id] = (lvelox[id] * -1);
            xcord[id] = xcord[id] + lvelox[id];
            ycord[id] = ycord[id] + lveloy[id];
            printf("%f, %f, %d, %d\n", xcord[id], ycord[id], id, step);
    }

    if ( xcord[id] > length )
    {
            lvelox[id] = (lvelox[id] * -1);
            xcord[id] = xcord[id] + lvelox[id];
            ycord[id] = ycord[id] + lveloy[id];
            printf("%f, %f, %d, %d\n", xcord[id], ycord[id], id, step);
    }

    if ( xcord[j] == xcord[k] )
    {
            lvelox[j] = (lvelox[j] * -1);
            xcord[j] = xcord[j] + lvelox[j];
            ycord[j] = ycord[j] + lveloy[j];
            printf("%f, %f, %d, %d\n", xcord[j], ycord[j], j, step);
            lvelox[k] = (lvelox[k] * -1);
            xcord[k] = xcord[k] + lvelox[k];
            ycord[k] = ycord[k] + lveloy[k];
            printf("%f, %f, %d, %d\n", xcord[k], ycord[k], k, step);
    }

    if ( ycord[j] == ycord[k] )
    {
            lvelox[j] = (lvelox[j] * -1);
            xcord[j] = xcord[j] + lvelox[j];
            ycord[j] = ycord[j] + lveloy[j];
            printf("%f, %f, %d, %d\n", xcord[j], ycord[j], j, step);
            lvelox[k] = (lvelox[k] * -1);
            xcord[k] = xcord[k] + lvelox[k];
            ycord[k] = ycord[k] + lveloy[k];
            printf("%f, %f, %d, %d\n", xcord[k], ycord[k], k, step);
    }

    if ( step == stepcount )
    {
            return 0;
    }

    }

    step = step + 1;

}
}
```

This program simulates 1000 particles colliding in a box of user-defined dimensions. This code doesn't seem to work. It produces random coordinates that are outside the dimension of the box, and also does not show the coordinates of all the particles. This only occurred after inserting the collision section of the code.

```
    j = id
    k = id
    if ( xcord[j] == xcord[k] )
    {
            lvelox[j] = (lvelox[j] * -1);
            xcord[j] = xcord[j] + lvelox[j];
            ycord[j] = ycord[j] + lveloy[j];
            printf("%f, %f, %d, %d\n", xcord[j], ycord[j], j, step);
            lvelox[k] = (lvelox[k] * -1);
            xcord[k] = xcord[k] + lvelox[k];
            ycord[k] = ycord[k] + lveloy[k];
            printf("%f, %f, %d, %d\n", xcord[k], ycord[k], k, step);
    }

    if ( ycord[j] == ycord[k] )
    {
            lvelox[j] = (lvelox[j] * -1);
            xcord[j] = xcord[j] + lvelox[j];
            ycord[j] = ycord[j] + lveloy[j];
            printf("%f, %f, %d, %d\n", xcord[j], ycord[j], j, step);
            lvelox[k] = (lvelox[k] * -1);
            xcord[k] = xcord[k] + lvelox[k];
            ycord[k] = ycord[k] + lveloy[k];
            printf("%f, %f, %d, %d\n", xcord[k], ycord[k], k, step);
    }
```

Comment: The equality operator is `==` and not `=`. Also you can't have a list of indices or something like that in C. You should revisit the basic concepts of C.

Comment: your `if` statement doesn't make any sense. do you mean a `for` loop instead?

Comment: Now, it should compile.

Comment: But it produces random values that doesn't make sense. I am simulating 1000 particles colliding with each other in a box.

Comment: Show your full code. It seems that you are using some uninitialized variables.

Comment: I suggest you to first read some basic C book/tutorial. When I compiled your code in my compiler my IDE get crashed. I can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're trying to do, but this line doesn't make any sense at all:

```
   if ( xcord[id] = xcord[id = 0; id < 1000; id++] )
```

There is no C syntax that looks even remotely like that. This looks like half `if` and half `for`. Pick one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you did something really strange. Read first about loops and then try again. What I mean is you have to use

```
for(id = 0; id < 1000; id++) {
   //your code here
}
```

Comment: He wants to compare the array elements.

Comment: I know but he doesn't want to compare only first element with the second one so he has to iterate over whole array, doesn't he?

Comment: I made some modifications to the code, but it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I assume you do this in a loop. Notice that `j=id; k=id` means that `j==k` and i think it wasn't your purpose. If you want to compare two array's elements you have to pick first one and then iterate over the array and check if this first one is the same as `your_tab[id]`. Try to better compose your question or say what do you want to get as output.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
   int xcord[] = {1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7};
   int arrlength= sizeof(xcord)/sizeof(xcord[0]);
   int i,j,tmp;
   for(i=0; i<arrlength; i++) {
       tmp = xcord[i];
       for (j=i+1; j<arrlength; j++) {
           if(xcord[i] == xcord[j]) {
               printf("same value %d \n",xcord[j]);
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Are there any imports that I should make when using this?

Comment: just edited my answer with exact working code. you can check online here http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php